# `dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:" dismisses keyboard and not VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `ViewController` with an `UISearchController` inside (with a table view on it). I've added this line on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

For some reason, the `viewController` isn't being dismissed and instead, the keyboard is being dismissed (the `searchController` becomes inactive), to dismiss the `viewController` I have to reselect a cell on the table (and then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is being called twice).

Any idea why is it happening?

Thank you!

Comment: try `presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening because `UISearchController` inherits from `UIViewController` and therefore the controller being dismissed in `didSelectRow` is actually the search controller.

Perhaps simply try dismissing twice so that it removes the search controller followed by your custom view controller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It's working but then the animation is really fast and it looks bad, how can I set a delay between the first dismiss to the second?

Comment: You can next the second dismiss inside the completion block of the first one, but I'm not quite comfortable with this approach.

Comment: Could you perhaps try only animating the second dismiss?

Answer (score 0):

Try to resigning keyboard first and then dismiss vc.